# При запуске jar файла выдает ошибку : Error: JavaFx runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, javafx, jar

Продолжил бороться с данной проблемой. Скачал последний javaFX-sdk версии 17.0.0.1 (September 2021).
Через батник пытаюсь открыть таким образом:

```
java --module-path C:\Program_Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics -jar C:\Users\USER\IdeaProjects\keys\out\artifacts\keys_jar\keys.jar
```

[image: Не может найти controls]

Через intellij приложение запускается без проблем.
Если нужна дополнительная информация, только скажите.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Прикладывайте к вопросу тесктовую информацию текстом. Удобнее копировать, цитировать и обрабатывать

Answer (score 0):

Я запускаю так:

```
java --module-path c:\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar [fullpath]\myjar.jar
```